# Terminate Angular Promises Execution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have few methods to execute for the syncing task. I'm using `$q.all` to save the sync data into the local database after resolving all the promises. This application allows user to start sync and cancel ongoing sync. So I want to cancel all the promises execution OR reject to stop on going execution. Here is my sample code.http://plnkr.co/edit/cMbFs0JZJjF1dC4IavDJ?p=preview

Any idea how to stop these execution? or any other suggestion to terminate method execution

Answer (score 0):

i don't think there is a kill method, because js is single thread based, event driven, u need a working flag in controller or scope, check this flag every loop, case give up, resolve or reject

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved something like this -

1. create a global request array (pendingRequests)
2. create custom httpService for calling http ajax calls (`httpService.get(url,data`)
3. cancelSync can be achieved by calling `pendingRequests.cancelAll()`

   ```
                 .service('pendingRequests', function() {
                     var pending = [];

                     this.cancelAll = function() {
                       angular.forEach(pending, function(p) {
                         p.canceller.resolve();
                       });
                       pending.length = 0;
                     };
                   })
                   .service('httpService', ['$http', '$q', 'pendingRequests', function($http, $q, pendingRequests) {
                     this.get = function(url,data) {
                       var canceller = $q.defer();
                       pendingRequests.add({
                         url: url,
                         canceller: canceller
                       });
                       data.timeout = canceller.promise;

                       //Request gets cancelled if the timeout-promise is resolved
                       var requestPromise = $http.get(url,data);
                       //Once a request has failed or succeeded, remove it from the pending list
                       requestPromise.finally(function() {
                         pendingRequests.remove(url);
                       });
                       return requestPromise;
                     }
                   }])
   ```